# Preventing Apps from Uninstall

Tags: android

I am building a security app for an enterprise and I have disabled apps getting uninstalled from Settings or from Long Press and Delete. However, I found that apps can also be unistalled through Play Store where they have two option - Open and Uninstall.
How can I overcome this ?

In case I lock PlayStore, Apps do not get Updated, user cannot install new apps or search for any apps.

To disable uninstall button or option in Playstore or any hack to it.

Comment: You should install your app as system app

Comment: You can make your app device administrator so it won't be uninstalled directly from home screen or play store.

Comment: in general you can't do that and should not be able to do that. Even device admin app can be uninstalled.